# Can I make Apache serve my Node.js server on a subdomain?

Tags: apache

Currently Apachi serves my my front-end project on `xxx.xx.xx.xx:80` and my domain name points to that. So when I go to [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) , my front-end project gets served.

I also have a Node.js project that runs on `xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000`. I'm curious if it is possible to make Apache serve the project, that is served on `xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000` by Node.js, on `www.api.domainname.com`. Sort of like a proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtualhost having ServerName the domain you want to use (not an IP address) and ServerAlias any other domain you want to configure and serve the same content.
You can read more informations about how to configure a virtualhost here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html